# Access content script by injected script

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have a content script where I define a small task api, I would like to access this api (namespace) through the script injected by browser.tabs; executeScript (). for example:

```
//contentScript.js
const api = new (function () {
     this.doSomething()
})();


// injectedScript

console.log (api.doSomething ())
```

It is possible? If yes, how?

I'm trying to do this, and am getting a RefereceError.
Being the content script and the script injected, considered by the content scripts documentation, why do not they see each other?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The symbol `api` in your content script is a const, which is not visible outside that specific script.  The two scripts run in the same global so `var api = ...` or simply `function api() { ... }` should work.

Comment: I change the const to var.. "Uncaught ReferenceError: api is not defined"